# GRUB menu does not appear after setting up dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I decided to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 8. Everything went right during the process (partitioning, installing, etc) but upon rebooting my laptop (my laptop is an HP Pavilion G6) it booted straight into Windows 8 with no GRUB menu to be seen. I attempted to use boot repair on Ubuntu and that failed; I also tried to change the boot order in the BIOS although I'm not really sure what I'm doing there so I don't know if I did it right or not.

Some help would be brilliant as I'm not sure how to go about getting the GRUB menu back!

Comment: You might want to know this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/484895/not-able-to-get-grub-boot-menu-dual-boot-ubuntu-wndows-8/484902#484902

Comment: Thank you for this, boot menu is now present. Only thing is that I can't boot into Ubuntu? It displays an error stating that there has been a recent software or hardware change, that makes it unable to go and further. Could this be due to the 'easYBDC' program?

Comment: Can you tell me the exact error message.

Comment: Okay the error message is as follows: Windows is unable to boot. This could be due to a recent software or hardware change. to fix the problem: 1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your pc. 2. Choose your language settings then click 'next'. 3. click 'repair your pc. It then goes onto to state the file which is /NST/AutoNeoBrub.mbr, the status which is 0xc000007b. Lastly it says: the application or OS could'nt be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors. Sorry if this is too much information, I just did'nt know what to include. Thanks! :D

Comment: Did you do what it said to do?

Comment: Yes, did'nt go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely solved by the official documentation in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI.

Some things to examine closely including the window 'faststart', and indeed the Bios boot order.  You *want* to load the grub boot loader (Ubuntu) first, and from there you can choose to boot Windows 8, or continue with booting Ubuntu.